# select minus operator in dplyr group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

Does anyone know of a fast way to select 'all-but-one' (or 'all-but-a-few') columns when using `dplyr::group_by`?
Ultimately, I just want to aggregate over all distinct rows after removing a few select columns, but I don't want to have to explicitly list all the grouping columns each time (since those get added and removed somewhat frequently in my analysis).

Example:

```
 > df <- data_frame(a = c(1,1,2,2), b = c("foo", "foo", "bar", "bar"), c = runif(4))
 > df
 Source: local data frame [4 x 3]

       a     b          c
   (dbl) (chr)      (dbl)
 1     1   foo 0.95460749
 2     1   foo 0.05094088
 3     2   bar 0.93032589
 4     2   bar 0.40081121
```

Now I want to aggregate by `a` and `b`, so I can do this:

```
 > df %>% group_by(a, b) %>% summarize(mean(c))
 Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
 Groups: a [?]

       a     b   mean(c)
   (dbl) (chr)     (dbl)
 1     1   foo 0.5027742
 2     2   bar 0.6655686
```

Great.
But, I'd *really* like to be able to do something like just specify **not** `c`, similar to `dplyr::select(-c)`:

```
 > df %>% select(-c)
 Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

       a     b
   (dbl) (chr)
 1     1   foo
 2     1   foo
 3     2   bar
 4     2   bar
```

But `group_by` can apply expressions, so the equivalent doesn't work:

```
 > df %>% group_by(-c) %>% summarize(mean(c))
 Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

            -c    mean(c)
         (dbl)      (dbl)
 1 -0.95460749 0.95460749
 2 -0.93032589 0.93032589
 3 -0.40081121 0.40081121
 4 -0.05094088 0.05094088
```

Anyone know if I'm just missing a basic function or shortcut to help me do this quickly?

Example use case: if `df` suddenly gains a new column `d`, I'd like the downstream code to now aggregate over unique combinations of `a`, `b`, *and* `d`, without me having to explicitly add `d` to the `group_by` call.)

Comment: `df %>% group_by_(.dots = setdiff(names(df), "c")) %>% summarize(mean(c))` maybe?

Comment: Yup, that's what I've settled on, it just seems ... clunky, somehow. I thought there might be some (unknown to me) function that 'protects' expressions like `-c` from immediate evaluation which can then be treated as if they were made in a `select` call. But generally, yes, `group_by_` and `setdiff` can do the trick, thanks!

Comment: I agree that one could think this should work as this looks like a typical dplyr syntax Maybe look up if there is existing FR on GH, or maybe this was implemented in the development version. If not, you could make a FR and see how it goes.

Comment: Not any better than @DavidArenburg's `setdiff` but still within the Hadleyverse would be something like `df %>% group_by_(.dots = select_vars(names(.), -c)) %>% summarize(mean(c))`, I guess.

Comment: Currently, you could use `across()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current versions of dplyr, the function `group_by_at`, together with `vars`, accomplishes this goal:

```
df %>% group_by_at(vars(-c)) %>% summarize(mean(c))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   a [?]
      a     b  `sum(c)`
  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
1     1   foo 0.9851376
2     2   bar 1.0954412
```

Appears to have been introduced in dplyr 0.7.0, in June 2017

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pick` or `across`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(pick(- c)) %>% # or group_by(across(- c))
  summarize(mean(c))

#       a b     `mean(c)`
#   <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
# 1     1 foo       0.543
# 2     2 bar       0.911
```